# Where can I find a copy of the HiSoft C compiler manual for ZX Spectrum?

Tags: zx-spectrum, compilers, documentation

I've been able to find the manual for the CPC version of HiSoft C, but not for the ZX. The only ones I could find appeared to have been OCRed, so virtually all of the necessary information was lost.

Related to [Native C compiler for Sinclair ZX Spectrum](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6080/8090)

Comment: I found http://www.users.globalnet.co.uk/~jg27paw4/pourri/hisoft_c.htm, but it doesn't seem to be complete.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find any "pure scan", only the OCRed one, but here is an interesting link to HiSoft C disassembled code with some documentation, if you are deeply interested: https://github.com/oldcompcz/HiSoft-C/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I have an original one, but sadly of an earlier version.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Did the earlier version change particularly drastically?

Comment: I'm have no idea about content tbh. later ones are more polished, this one seems written by a typewriter.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, there doesn't seem to be a ‘pure scan’ available, but there are endless copies of this: [HiSoft C Manual for ZX Spectrum (pdf)](https://worldofspectrum.net/pub/sinclair/games-info/h/HiSoftC.pdf). While I don't share your aversion to OCR'd manuals (and having done a few myself, I'd not let one out the door unless it had *fewer* typos than the original …) you might wish to refer to the [HiSoft C Manual for Amstrad CPC & CP/M](http://www.cpcwiki.eu/imgs/a/a0/Hisoft_C_%28Hisoft%29_Manual.pdf): it is a scan, and seems very complete. You will have to refer to the OCR copy for Spectrum-specific routines, though.

I understand that HiSoft C was originally developed by compiling code using the CP/M [BDS C](https://www.bdsoft.com/resources/bdsc.html) system, then manually porting the result to each target Z80 system. The ZX Spectrum and Amstrad versions have very similar compilers, with the major differences being in the runtime library.